# Can we start foreground service from Work Manager?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

I am starting foreground service from the work manager doWork method.

1. Is it ok to do so?
2. startForegroundService should call startForeground within 5 seconds otherwise exception will happen. How to prevent this? (Note I have added startForeground in onCreate of Service)

   ```
    override fun doWork(): Result {

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.setClassName(App.context.packageName, "com.xyz.MySerivce")
            intent.putExtra("sync_service_initiate", true)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                applicationContext.startForegroundService(intent)
                applicationContext.stopService(intent)
            } else {
                applicationContext.startService(intent)
            }
           return Result.success()
    }
   ```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to start the foreground service in work manager?

Comment: @DanielWeidensdörfer an example might be to chain the work :) but I agree that it can be done just sequentially line-by-line execution as this is not blocking request.

Comment: I think for chaining work there are better ways than trying to start a service from work manager :)

Answer (score 0):

In Android 12 and above you cannot start Foreground Service from Background thread, so due to this limitation it is not possible.
The Work Manager will start the Foreground Service when it is executed for the first time but as the worker executes after every 15 Minutes, so when it will try to execute the Foreground Service for the second time than, you will get warning or error that worker cannot start Foreground Service from Background thread.

Comment: Note: `Background thread` is not same as `App running in background`